# Can't get Git to work over TeamViewer VPN / Proxy

Tags: git, ssh, proxy, vpn

I have a work computer, which connects to a Git repository on my work network.

I've installed TeamViewer on that machine and I'm using TeamViewer VPN to connect to that computer from my personal laptop.

I'm also running a proxy application called [ReDirProxy](http://redirproxy.bplaced.net) in order to access my work network from my laptop, including the Git server.

I can connect to the Git server through SSH using PuTTY, by specifying the proxy settings in PuTTY prior to connecting. I've saved these settings under a profile called 'Git'.

I can also connect to other servers on the work network through my browser. So clearly there's nothing wrong with the VPN or proxy per-se.

However when I try to access git through the command-line it never seems to work.

- If I try to ping the git server, it doesn't work.
- If I try to clone from the git server, using the PuTTY profile name (e.g. `git clone git@Git:myrepo.git`), git just hangs at the command-line.
- If I open a git repository which has remotes configured to point at my PuTTY profile (e.g. `git@Git.myrepo.git`) and try to do a `pull` or `fetch`, git just hangs at the command-line.

I've tried specifying my proxy server for git, using the `git config --global http.proxy xyz:123` command, but to no avail.

I don't understand why Git doesn't work, but PuTTY SSH works. Is there some configuration that PuTTY has, so that it works through my VPN/Proxy, which isn't getting through to git?

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Some extra details for those who want them: I'm running Windows 2008 Server R2 on both computers. I'm using MSysGit and GitExtensions. I'm running all my git commands through a PowerShell command prompt.

Comment: Also this is clearly not an issue with my VPN/Proxy per-se, as I can connect to the Git server through PuTTY and I can browse to various other servers on the network through my web browser on my personal laptop. However it might be an issue with Git not knowing about my proxy and attempting to go directly to the Git server from my laptop's connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, got it working now! Just had to use different proxy software - FreeProxy Internet Suite from [Handcrafted Software](http://www.handcraftedsoftware.org/).

I believe the difference was the ReDirProxy didn't support NTLM, whereas FreeProxy does. (I ticked the box to enable NTLM in the proxy settings window on FreeProxy.)